# Stuck transferring God of War Ragnarök saved data from PS4 to PS5

Tags: ps4, ps5, god-of-war-ragnarok

I got a PS5 today and wanted to transfer my saved data of *GOWR* from PS4 to PS5. The system transfer worked and I can see the game saves on the PS5 game. But when loading in it get stuck on a progress bar.

[image: screenshot of described issue]

Do I have to restart it?

I'm going to do that on a harder difficulty anyways but I was wondering if there is a chance to get the progress back to explore more of the game since I rushed through the story to avoid spoilers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last update released solved the problem.